# How to access the source code of the interface functions .Call in R language?

Tags: r

I have tried to search for the source code of the interface function ".Call(C_SplineCoef,...)" that is mentioned in splinefun {stats} as follows:

```
z <- .Call(C_SplineCoef, min(3L, iMeth), x, y)
```

But could not help myself to explore it.

Comment: you could go to https://github.com/wch/r-source and search for SplineCoef , which leads to https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SplineCoef&type=  ,and choosing one    https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/src/splines.c

Comment: Thank you @user2957945. Can you please tell me how can I access the source code from within RStudio?

Comment: as far as i am aware you cant *easily*. I suppose you could download the package source, unzip,  then use grep to search the files for SplineCoef.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display the code directly in Rstudio; however, you can use the pryr package to automatically search the correct source file for you on github.

First, look at the source of the R function:

```
is.unsorted

# function (x, na.rm = FALSE, strictly = FALSE)
# {
#   if (length(x) <= 1L)
#     return(FALSE)
#   if (!na.rm && anyNA(x))
#     return(NA)
#   if (na.rm && any(ii <- is.na(x)))
#     x <- x[!ii]
#   .Internal(is.unsorted(x, strictly))
# }
```

and then use:

```
pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(is.unsorted(x, strictly)))
```

to automatically open a browser window to
https://github.com/search?q=SEXP%20attribute_hidden%20do_isunsorted+repo:wch/r-source&type=Code